# Dump in memory sqlite using jooq context to byte[]

Tags: sqlite, jooq

Need to now get byte[] from in memory db as below.

```
 DSLContext dsl = DSL.using("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

- Can we use DSLContext to get inputstream / byteArray ?
- If multiple such "in memory" contexts are created in separate threads, can there  be any race condition w.r.t sqlite read /write from DSLContext side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ side of your question is quite easy to answer. What you're doing there is incomplete. If you're using the [`DSL.using(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-), [`DSL.using(String, Properties)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-), or [`DSL.using(String, String, String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) methods, you will get a *"resourceful"* `DSLContext`, which you have to close yourself (in order to close the underlying JDBC connection. E.g.:

```java
try (DSLContext dsl = DSL.using("jdbc:sqlite::memory:") {
    ...
}
```

Do note that jOOQ creates an underlying JDBC connection for you and operates on that for all methods called on `dsl`. Apart from that, everything works exactly the same way as if you had been using a JDBC connection as such:

```java
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:") {
    ...
}
```

#### Regarding your specific questions:

> Can we use DSLContext to get inputstream / byteArray ?

Of course, just fetch a byte array from your database using jOOQ, there's nothing special about it.

> If multiple such "in memory" contexts are created in separate threads, can there be any race condition w.r.t sqlite read /write from DSLContext side ?

Without formally validating the docs, this can be checked empirically relatively simply:

```java
try (
    DSLContext ctx1 = DSL.using("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
    DSLContext ctx2 = DSL.using("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
) {
    ctx1.execute("create table x (i int primary key, j varchar(10))");
    ctx1.execute("insert into x values (1, 'c1')");
    ctx2.execute("create table x (i int primary key, j varchar(10))");
    ctx2.execute("insert into x values (1, 'c2')");

    System.out.println(ctx1.fetch("select i, j from x"));
    System.out.println(ctx2.fetch("select i, j from x"));
}
```

Not only is there no exception when re-creating the table x, there is also no constraint violation on the second insertion of the primary key value `1`. The output being:

```
+----+----+
|   i|j   |
+----+----+
|   1|c1  |
+----+----+

+----+----+
|   i|j   |
+----+----+
|   1|c2  |
+----+----+
```

And, as soon as you close the connection / `DSLContext`, the data is gone

Comment: Thanks Lukas, figuring this one out " fetch a byte array from your database using jOOQ" . I think will have to execute dsl.execute(" DUMP "). basically need to get full dump of  in memory sqlite db , not just few tables

Comment: i checked SQLiteConnection but could not find any getInputStream .

Comment: @fortm: About those byte arrays, I'll be very happy to answer additional follow up questions with details about the exact data set that you want to fetch from the database. I think it's better to ask a new question rather than edit this one...

Comment: created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102512/backup-in-memory-sqlite-db-to-byte-array-using-jooq-context