# backup in memory sqlite db to byte array using jooq Context

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jooq

```java
private byte[] inMemSqliteDbBackup() {
    byte[] data = null;
    try (DSLContext dsl = DSL.using("jdbc:sqlite::memory:") {
        ...
        //insert some data 
        dsl.execute("backup to " + data); // backup to byte[], but unsupported , a file is needed 
        dsl.connection(connection -> {
            // or, get underlying connection and open inputstream 
            // but there is no getInputStream in SqliteConnection
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

How can we backup in memory sqlite db to byte[] ?
I went through SqliteConnection and it does not give an InputStream either.

one option is to not use in memory db by using url as "`jdbc:sqlite:/some-location`" and then we can use `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(some-location))` , but not sure if we can do the same with in memory sqlite db and still using DSLContext by Jooq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `backup to` syntax is not a native SQLite SQL syntax, but [offered by the Xerial JDBC driver according to their docs here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Usage#markdown-header-how-to-use-online-backup-and-restore-feature):

> Take a backup of the whole database to backup.db file:
>
> ```java
> // Create a memory database
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:");
> Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
> // Do some updates
> stmt.executeUpdate("create table sample(id, name)");
> stmt.executeUpdate("insert into sample values(1, \"leo\")");
> stmt.executeUpdate("insert into sample values(2, \"yui\")");
> // Dump the database contents to a file
> stmt.executeUpdate("backup to backup.db");
> Restore the database from a backup file:
> // Create a memory database
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:");
> // Restore the database from a backup file
> Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
> stat.executeUpdate("restore from backup.db");
> ```

If you reverse engineer their sources, you can see that the command is intercepted, and translated to this particular method in `org.sqlite.core.NativeDB`:

```java
native synchronized int backup(byte[] dbNameUtf8, byte[] destFileNameUtf8,
        ProgressObserver observer) throws SQLException;
```

I.e. it is bound to the SQLite backup API, which can operate only with actual files, not with in-memory data structures.

So, I'm afraid you cannot, with the current versions of SQLite, intercept that backup and send that into a `byte[]` variable, without an intermediate temporary file being written, regardless if using jOOQ or JDBC or native SQLite directly